# How do you call CMFCRibbonProgressBar methods from a different thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mfc

I have a simple CMFCRibbonProgressBar and a thread that calls SetPos(value, TRUE) on it when a lengthy operation progresses.
The problem is that in debug mode it asserts in wincore.cpp with this:

```
    CHandleMap* pMap = afxMapHWND();
    ASSERT(pMap != NULL);
```

I understand by the comments in that file that I shouldn't be calling it from a different thread because it could potentially be dangerous.
My question then is how do you get a thread to update the position of the progress bar ?
I'm very tempted to just ignore that assert and continue in release mode but that's pretty evil...

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, someone commented very briefly on the question and they had the right answer. I don't know why they retracted their comment :/

I ended up storing a CWnd* pointer in the CMFCRibbonProgressBar derived class, and whenever I call the "SetAmountCompleted" method from the worker thread, I use the CWnd to send a custom message with a pointer to the derived class in the WPARAM.
The CWnd that receives the message then extracts the pointer and calls Update method which will redraw the progress bar.

It's complicated, it's ugly, it's MFC. Phew.

Comment: No, it's not MFC, it's not ugly. The fact is that manipulating a window from a thread different than the one who created it is a no-no. The correct strategy is to somehow send the update request to the UI thread (posting a WM_USER+x is a good idea) and let the handler figure out how to achieve the task. The worker should not know the details of your UI anyway.

Comment: The worker does not know anything about the UI, it only gets a pointer to an interface IProgressNotification which has SetTotal and SetAmountCompleted. The CMFCRibbonProgressBar derived class inherits from that and the said ribbon progress bar. In fact, the actual worker thread is in a separate library that has no knowledge of MFC whatsoever. As you can see the problem is that this derived class receives the notification and then updates the UI, which MFC does not like. Instead now I have to get involved in some dirty business with a CWnd which just adds complexity :/